# Creating stripe payment token after validating other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, stripe-payments

To keep this simple I have only included one of the forms I am validating. Everything validates right, but I can't figure out why a token does not get generated. The form never submits. I had the form working right without validating not sure what the problem is.

```
var oeValidate = {
    'name' : function() {
        var ele = $('#name');

        if(ele.val().length < 6) {
            oeValidate.errors = true;
            ele.removeClass('correct').addClass('error');
        } else {
            ele.removeClass('error').addClass('correct');
        }
    },

    'sendIt' : function() {
        if(!oeValidate.errors) {
            $('#payment-form').submit(function(event){
                // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
                $('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

                // send the card details to Stripe
                Stripe.createToken({
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    number: $('#card-number').val(),
                    exp_month: $('select[name="card-month"]').val(),
                    exp_year: $('select[name="card-year"]').val(),
                    cvc: $('#card-cvc').val()
                }, stripeResponseHandler);

                // prevent the form from submitting the default action
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
};

Stripe.setPublishableKey(stripe_vars.publishable_key);

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) {
        // show errors returned by Stripe
        jQuery(".payment-errors").html(response.error.message);
        // re-enable the submit button
        jQuery('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        var form$ = jQuery("#payment-form");
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response['id'];
        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        form$.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "'/>");
        // and submit
        form$.get(0).submit();
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#stripe-submit').click(function (){
        oeValidate.errors = false;
        oeValidate.name();
        oeValidate.sendIt();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Needed to not have the submit function as a method.

```
$('#payment-form').submit(function(event){
    // validate fields
    oeValidate.errors = false;
    oeValidate.name();

    // send the card details to Stripe
    if(!oeValidate.errors){
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        Stripe.createToken({
            name: $('#name').val(),
            number: $('#card-number').val(),
            exp_month: $('select[name="card-month"]').val(),
            exp_year: $('select[name="card-year"]').val(),
            cvc: $('#card-cvc').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }

    // prevent the form from submitting the default action
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

suppose you have to use

```
Stripe.createToken($(this), stripeResponseHandler);
```

I mean the first parameter must be your form object and your form must contain specified fields, but not an object, that you are trying to create

then `response` will contain this info

check this [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms)

Comment: so are you saying I cannot store this information in an object?

Comment: @ftntravis  as docs say, you must use `$('form').submit(function() {$form = $(this); ... Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler); ... });`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that did not help.